# reportlab background color of page (BaseDocTemplate)

Tags: reportlab

I just want simple set background color of page. But with report lab you should use left hand to catch right ear under your knee... I googled for it, but everywhere is simple anser - create Rect with color. BUT HOW?!?!?!?!?!?

```
doc = BaseDocTemplate(buffer)

Elements=[]

#Two Columns
frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col1')
frame2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin+doc.width/2+6, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col2')

Elements.append(Paragraph('HEADING',styles['Heading1']))
Elements.append(Paragraph('Lorem Ipsum Dolor', styles['Normal']))

doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='TwoCol',frames=[frame1,frame2]), ])


doc.build(Elements)
```

I tried to use Drawing, but 0,0 isn't  left bottom coordinates of page but left bottom coordinates of Drawing... But how set Drawing to left bottom - don't know...

```
 draw = Drawing(500, 200)
 rectangle = Rect(0,0,100,100)
 color = PCMYKColor(15,9,0,8)
 rectangle.fillColor = color
 rectangle.strokeColor = color
 draw.add(rectangle)

 Elements.append(draw)
```

I found, that doc.width and doc.height would be great for top right coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

The solution which works for me:

```
 Elements=[]

 def setBackground(canvas, document):
     color = PCMYKColor(15,9,0,8)
     canvas.setFillColor(color)
     canvas.rect(0,0,doc.width+doc.leftMargin+doc.rightMargin,doc.height+doc.topMargin+doc.bottomMargin, fill=True, stroke=False)

 #Two Columns
 frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col1')
 frame2 = Frame(doc.leftMargin+doc.width/2+6, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width/2-6, doc.height, id='col2')


 Elements.append(Paragraph('HEADING',styles['Heading1']))
 Elements.append(Paragraph('Lorem Ipsum Dolor', styles['Normal'])

 doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='TwoCol',frames=[frame1,frame2],onPage=setBackground) ])


 #start the construction of the pdf
 doc.build(Elements)
```